# pull one table and column from another table and column?

Tags: mysql

I want the display to show a single unit of information. For example, I want ID 1 'jscbb_directory' to show the information of only ID 1 'pictures' column.  Instead it is displaying everything in pictures.picture.

```
SELECT jscbb_directory.id, pictures.picture
FROM jscbb_directory, pictures
WHERE jscbb_directory.id = pictures.picture;
```

OUTPUTS:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I am using fourwinds as a front-end and I would like it so when the user clicks ID 1 'jscbb_directory' it displays ONLY the information from ID 1 of 'pictures'

Comment: You want to use a `JOIN`.

Comment: @BackinaFlash they are using a `JOIN`. The join is in the where clause

Answer (score 3):

try specifie the id you want to show

like that

```
    SELECT jscbb_directory.id, pictures.picture
    FROM jscbb_directory, pictures
     WHERE jscbb_directory.id = pictures.picture
     AND jscbb_directory.id = 1;   // <--------- put the id number you want or the variable $id
```

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you use `JOIN` with an `ON` clause. Not because it fixes a problem, but because it makes it easier to read.

`SELECT` whatever you like. Pick which columns you want here.
`FROM jscbb_directory JOIN pictures ON jscbb_directory.id = pictures.picture`

Now you have the same thing you had before, but a little more readable.

So now add a filter to the end. `where jscbb_directory.id=1;`

Feel free to clarify what you are trying to do. I am not sure I understand your question.

---

Here is my answer again, all in one piece.

```
SELECT jscbb_directory.id, pictures.picture
FROM jscbb_directory JOIN pictures ON jscbb_directory.id = pictures.picture
WHERE jscbb_directory.id = 1;
```

and, it outputs

```
+----+---------+
| id | picture |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       1 |
+----+---------+
```

I don't know why you want the same thing twice. So perhaps you should just try this

```
SELECT jscbb_directory.id
FROM jscbb_directory JOIN pictures ON jscbb_directory.id = pictures.picture
WHERE jscbb_directory.id = 1;
```

or this

```
SELECT pictures.*
FROM jscbb_directory JOIN pictures ON jscbb_directory.id = pictures.picture
WHERE jscbb_directory.id = 1;
```

and see what they do

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mixing up the use of a JOIN condition with a WHERE clause filter. You should be explicit about your JOIN condition using an `ON` or `USING` clause, and teh apply the filter condition in your WHERE. So it should look like this:

```
SELECT jscbb_directory.id, pictures.picture
FROM jscbb_directory
INNER JOIN pictures ON jscbb_directory.id = pictures.picture
WHERE jscbb_directory.id = ?
```

Where `?` is replaced by the id you are filtering for.